# HTML content depending on the domain

Tags: html

I have two domains refering to the same `index.html`. I want to have different main headings depending on the called Domain.

```
e.g.: 
domain1.com --> Wellcome to Domain1 
domain2.com --> Wellcome to Domain2
```

What do you think would be the best approach to solve this? I was thinking on JS that identifies the domain/url and inserts the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need to do it dynamically? All that is going to do is make things more difficult for yourself.

Especially the fact main headings will get picked up by search engines and any JavaScript which changes that means nothing.

I would suggest (if anything) doing this with a server side language...

Comment: It MAY be relevant for intranet-applications

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution:

You can get the domain with `document.domain`. With that it's easy to write it somewhere on the page. Just like this:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 'Welcome to ' + document.domain);
```